# Tic tac toe game in python doesn't work properly

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

As a beginner coder, I'm trying to make tic tac toe in python. problem is, after it ask "start new game?" your answer doesn't matter. The game starts and prompts the player for a move. It changes the appropriate place to and x and then does the computer move without any problems. But after that it automatically becomes a draw (sometimes a win) and the game is over. What have I done wrong?

I realize the code's probably very clumsily made - but I'm a beginner; go easy on me, but here it is:

```
import random

def pl_mov():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    global e
    global f
    global g
    global h
    global i 
    while True:
        PL_INP = eval(input('ENTER THE NUMBER OF THE POSITION WHERE YOU WANT TO PUT YOUR CROSS:\n'))
        MOV = ''
        if PL_INP == 1 and a == '1':
            a = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 2 and b == '2':
            b = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 3 and c == '3':
            c = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 4 and d == '4':
            d = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 5 and e == '5':
            e = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 6 and f == '6':
            f = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 7 and g == '7':
            g = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 8 and h == '8':
            h = 'x'
            break
        if PL_INP == 9 and i == '9':
            i = 'x'
            break
        else:
            print('NOT A VALID MOVE!')

def COM_MOV():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    global d
    global e
    global f
    global g
    global h
    global i
    mov = 0

    POSSB = ['']
    if a == '1':
        POSSB.append('a')
    if b == '2':
        POSSB.append('b')
    if c == '3':
        POSSB.append('c')
    if d == '4':
        POSSB.append('d')
    if e == '5':
        POSSB.append('e')
    if f == '6':
        POSSB.append('f')
    if g == '7':
        POSSB.append('g')
    if h == '8':
        POSSB.append('h')
    if i == '9':
        POSSB.append('i')

    if a and b == 'o' and c == '3':
        if mov == 0:
            c = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if a and d == 'o' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if b and c == 'o' and a == '1':
        if mov == 0:
            a = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if b and e == 'o' and h == '8':
        if mov == 0:
            h = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if c and f == 'o' and i == '9':
        if mov == 0:
            i = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if a and d == 'o' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if d and e == 'o' and f == '6':
        if mov == 0:
            c = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if d and g == 'o' and a == '1':
        if mov == 0:
            a = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if e and b == 'o' and h == '8':
        if mov == 0:
            h = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if e and f == 'o' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if e and h == 'o' and b == '2':
        if mov == 0:
            b = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if f and c == 'o' and i == '9':
        if mov == 0:
            i = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if f and i == 'o' and c == '3':
        if mov == 0:
            c = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if g and h == 'o' and i == '9':
        if mov == 0:
            i = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if h and i == 'o' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if a and b == 'x' and c == '3':
        if mov == 0:
            c = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if a and d == 'x' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if b and c == 'x' and a == '1':
        if mov == 0:
            a = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if b and e == 'x' and h == '8':
        if mov == 0:
            h = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if c and f == 'x' and i == '9':
        if mov == 0:
            i = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if a and d == 'x' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if d and e == 'x' and f == '6':
        if mov == 0:
            c = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if d and g == 'x' and a == '1':
        if mov == 0:
            a = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if e and b == 'x' and h == '8':
        if mov == 0:
            h = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if e and f == 'x' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if e and h == 'x' and b == '2':
        if mov == 0:
            b = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if f and c == 'x' and i == '9':
        if mov == 0:
            i = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if f and i == 'x' and c == '3':
        if mov == 0:
            c = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if g and h == 'x' and i == '9':
        if mov == 0:
            i = 'o'
            mov += 1
    if h and i == 'x' and g == '7':
        if mov == 0:
            g = 'o'
            mov += 1
    else:
        temp = random.choice(POSSB)
        if temp == 'a':
            a = 'o'
        if temp == 'b':
            b = 'o'
        if temp == 'c':
            c = 'o'
        if temp == 'd':
            d = 'o'
        if temp == 'e':
            r = 'o'
        if temp == 'f':
            f = 'o'
        if temp == 'g':
            g = 'o'
        if temp == 'h':
            h = 'o'
        if temp == 'i':
            i = 'o'
while True:
    new_game = input('START NEW GAME?\n')
    if new_game == 'y' or 'yes' or 'Y' or 'YES':
        win = False
        loss_type = 0
        a = '1'
        b = '2'
        c = '3'
        d = '4'
        e = '5'
        f = '6'
        g = '7'
        h = '8'
        i = '9'
        print('WELCOME TO TIC TAC TOE!\n')
        while True:
            print('', a, '|', b, '|', c, '\n', d, '|', e, '|', f, '\n', g, '|', h, '|', i, '\n')

            if a and b and c == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if d and e and f == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if g and h and i == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if a and d and g == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if b and e and h == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if c and f and i == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if a and b and c == 'o':
                break
            if d and e and f == 'o':
                break
            if g and h and i == 'o':
                break
            if a and d and g == 'o':
                break
            if b and e and h == 'o':
                break
            if c and f and i == 'o':
                break
            if a and e and i == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if a and e and 1 == 'o':
                break
            if c and e and g == 'x':
                win = True
                break
            if c and e and g == 'o':
                break
            if a and b and c and d and e and f and g and h and i == 'x' or 'o':
                loss_type = 1

            pl_mov()
            if a and b and c and d and e and f and g and h and i == 'x' or 'o':
                loss_type = 1
            COM_MOV()

        print('GAME OVER!\n')
        if win == True:
            print('YOU WON! CONGRATS!')
        if win == False:
            if loss_type == 0:
                print('YOU LOST.')
            if loss_type == 1:
                print('DRAW!')
    if new_game == 'n' or 'no' or 'N' or 'NO':
        break
    else:
        print('INVALID ANSWER!')
```

Comment: This is why debuggers are useful or, if you don't want to learn a debugger, just printing out values to make sure your functions and expressions are returning what they should be. That said, your problem is almost certainly your usage of `and`.

Answer (score 1):

An expression like `a and b == 'o'` in python will be evaluated to `True` if `a` is `True` and `b == 'o'` is `True`. This is probably not what you intended. Everything before and after an `and` should be its own independent expression.

```
a and b == 'o'
```

Should be:

```
a == 'o' and b == 'o'
```

Similarly:

```
a and b and c == 'x'
```

Should be:

```
a == 'x' and b == 'x' and c == 'x'
```

And so on.